# Dell Inspiron Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I have tried to partition my hard drive of 1 TB as follows:
System Disk - 120 GB
Office -      100 GB
Home -        700 GB

But the disk manager is allowing me to partition only upto 465 GB and the remaining 455 GB is in System drive itself. I want to partition as above but unable to do so. Is there a reason why this restriction is placed and is there a solution ?.. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious --- What is the strategy behind repartitioning your system drive at all, vs. leaving everything on Drive C:, since it is the same physical device?

Answer (score -1):

In disk manager, right click on C: then shrink drive! Select how much you want to shrink by (455-120?) then shrink. You should have 300~ GB unallocated space which you can then partition into :)

[Edit: Cool guide from HowToGeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: If you feel a link is important enough to link to, you should quote the relevant information from the link, otherwise the link must not be that important.  The author already seems to know how to shrink the partition though honestly based on the rest of the question's contents.

Comment: Actually he said 455 gb is stuck in the system partition therefore I suggested shrinking. I basically summarised the guide in my answer but just provided it as a more indepth and step by step guide, but I inferred that Aryan was quite computer literate so wouldn't need hand holding.